# Execute inside of back-quote command on ssh

Tags: shell, ssh

I want to execute commands on remote server via ssh, but if I execute the following shell script, the commands is executed on local server.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat << EOF > "cmd.txt"
  if [ `ls -1U "/home/" | wc -l` -gt "0" ]; then
    echo "not empty!"
  fi
EOF
cmd=`cat "cmd.txt"`
rm "cmd.txt"

ssh root@127.0.0.1 "${cmd}"
```

The reason why it does happen is inside of back-quote (``` `` ```) commands are evaluated before passing variable to ssh option.

I also tried quoting with single-quote (`''`) or curly braces (`{}`) like the following:

```
if [ '`ls -1U "/home/" | wc -l`' -gt "0" ]; then

if [ {`ls -1U "/home/" | wc -l`} -gt "0" ]; then
```

but the result is the same before.(and without `` will be test command's (`[`) error with too many arguments)
How can I fix this? Do you have any ideas? Please help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the commands in a script and execute it remote via ssh:

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 'bash -s' < script.sh
```

Works as long as there are no environment variables envolved.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build the commands upfront and store it in a file. You can directly use here-doc with `ssh` like this:

```
ssh -t -t root@127.0.0.1 <<'EOF'
if [ $(ls -1U /home/ | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "not empty!"
fi
exit
EOF
```

Another thing to note is that you're parsing output of `ls` which can be error prone in some cases where filenames have space/newlines etc.

Comment: Your suggestion is really cool one! I didn't know that I don't need to build the commands upfront and store it in a file. Many thanks!